# How to create predictable logging locations with sbt-native-packager

Tags: sbt-native-packager

I am using sbt-native-packager with the experimental Java Server archetype. I am trying to identify a conventional way to access my log files, and I'm wondering if anyone knows of a common approach here. Since I am using the Java Server archetype, I am getting a symlink /var/log/$app -> install_dir/$app/log, but it feels a little dirty and less portable to just have log4j open /var/log/$app/error.log directly.

[Update]

I ended up creating an object with run time path information:

```
object MakaraPaths {
  def getLogPath = new File(getJarPath, "../logs").getPath
  def getConfigPath = new File(getJarPath, "../conf").getPath

  def getJarPath = { 
    val regex = new Regex("(/.+/)*")
    val jarPath = Makara.getClass.getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation.getPath

    (regex findAllIn jarPath).mkString("")
  }
}
```

In my main method, I established a system property based on the new MakaraPaths object:

```
System.setProperty("logPath", MakaraPaths.getLogPath)
```

I also used this for my config file:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(MakaraPaths.getConfigPath, "application.conf"))
```

Ultimately, to load the log file, I used a System Property lookup:

```
<RollingFile name="fileAppender" fileName="${sys:logPath}/server.log" filePattern="${sys:logPath}/server_%d{yyMMdd}.log">
```

This gets me most of the way where I needed to be. It's not completely portable, but it does technically support my use case. (Deploying to Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use relative path in log4j configuration. Just write logs in logs/filename.log. 
During installation symlink install_dir/$app/logs -> /var/log/$app will be created, and all logs will be written in /var/log/$app/filename.log

Comment: I changed my log4j2.xml configuration to use a relative path.

<RollingFile name="fileAppender" fileName="../logs/server.log" filePattern="../logs/server_%d{yyMMdd}.log">

However, this only creates a folder in $whatever_folder_im_in/../logs. sbt-native-packager creates a symlink /usr/bin/$app -> /usr/share/$app/bin/$app which lets you start an instance from any folder, so I just get ../logs folder all over the system. 

It seems like I need to do some more research on the log4j2 configurations, like maybe finding the actual file location of the class calling the logger if that is possible.

Comment: Are u using upstart or systemV?

Comment: I am using the default Upstart method. No server loader is being specified. Also, it might be worth it to note that I am using the debian packaging with debian:package-bin.

Comment: And how do you start your application, what version of package do you use?

Comment: started with `sudo start makara`, using addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.7.0-M1"). however, while testing i would just execute `makara`, which would drop the files relative to CWD

Comment: The issue is that when you use upstart or systemV CWD is set to install directory, and when you just exec `makara` it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. I am observing that behavior now.